# How to use Popen with an interactive command? nslookup, ftp

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

Is there any way to use Popen with interactive commands? I mean nslookup, ftp, powershell... I read the whole subprocess documentation several times but I can't find the way.

What I have (removing the parts of the project which aren't of interest here) is:

```
from subprocess import call, PIPE, Popen

command = raw_input('>>> ')
command = command.split(' ')

process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)

execution = process.stdout.read()
error = process.stderr.read()

output = execution + error

process.stderr.close()
process.stdout.close()

print(output)
```

Basically, when I try to print the output with a command like `dir`, the output is a string, so I can work with the `.read()` on it. But when I try to use `nslookup` for example, the output isn't a string, so it can't be read, and the script enters in a deadlock.

I know that I can invoke `nslookup` in non-interactive mode, but that's not the point. I want to remove all the chances of a deadlock, and make it works with every command you can run in a normal `cmd`.

The real way the project works is through sockets, so the `raw_input` is a `s.recv()` and the output is sending back the output, but I have simplified it to focus on the problem.

Comment: are you sure it's deadlock? I'm sure you can type text. It's just that you don't see the prompts, which are redirected by Popen. Maybe `pexpect` module would be more useful for you.

Comment: What's the output of `nslookup`?

Comment: You're right Jean-François, I can type text! Now I have another problem... in the real way that I use it(executing the command trough sockets and sending back the output), how can I detect when a command is interactive, and allows to enter more commands from the client side?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to decompile the underlying program that the subprocess is invoking?  I don't think that (for instance) the subprocess is going to know in advance whether or not my program has a `raw_input()` method invocation in it.

Comment: @alex the output is a file object.

Sorry but I can't understand clearly your last answer, English isn't my native language and I've just been programming for one year, I realize the confusion must be a mix of both causes

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre do you mean replace what subprocess does with the module pexpect, or just for handling specific outputs? I've been taking a fast look above the doc of this module, but I haven't a clear idea of what it does.

Comment: it executes your program but triggers callbacks when some strings are found in the program output. Note that it can be emulated with `Popen` too.

Comment: @rents I just mean to say that I'm skeptical that the subprocess would know what kind of "thing" a given command line program is supposed to return in advance of running it.